# Connecting to database using msnodesqlv8 nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

I have the below nodejs code to connect to database:

```
const  sql  =  require("msnodesqlv8");
const connectionString = "Server={remote}; Database={Products}; Trusted_Connection=Yes;Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}; "
const query = "SELECT * FROM Products"
sql.query(connectionString,  query,   (err,  rows)  =>  {    
    console.log(rows);
});
```

This code works fine if I have Microsoft SQL studio installed, and I try to connect to a remote SQL server.

But when I run this code to connect to a remote SQL server from a Windows 2016 server which doesn't have any SQL installed, the server fails with sqlstate: 'IM002'

Could someone let me know what to do ? is there any dependencies I need to install?

My DevOps team is not allowing to install SQL studio in the specified box so is there any workaround ?:

Comment: If it's based on `msnodesql`, the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msnodesql#prerequisites) there says that you need the "SQL Server Native Client" installed. Looks like that can be installed individually via an MSI. Search for `sqlncli.msi` [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29065).

Comment: @cubrr thank you so much, is there a way of avoiding dependencies in the server box ? or this is the only way . I was planning to install the odbc driver but the client you pointed includes that too. SO wil ltry that and let you know.

Comment: Find another library that doesn't need a native driver, or investigate something like Docker.

Comment: @cubrr https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious and msnodesql were the two drivers i founc and both require ODBC to be installed

Comment: I would go for Docker then. Your DevOps team will probably prefer that solution. You could include the [`msodbcsql`](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/developer-get-started/node/ubuntu/#step-13-install-the-odbc-driver-and-sql-command-line-utility-for-sql-server) driver in your Docker image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for "**ODBC Data Sources**"

[image]

Now open it and goto driver tab:

[image]

You can see all the available drivers, as of now you are using "SQL Server Native Client 11.0" in your code:

```
Server={remote}; Database={Products}; Trusted_Connection=Yes;Driver={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};
```

Replace the driver with whatever available in your system.

Eg: if SQL server is available, use below connection string.

```
Server={remote}; Database={Products}; Trusted_Connection=Yes;Driver={SQL Server};
```

If you don't have ODBC Data source, then you have to install the SQL server NAtive 11 client from:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=29065

click install instruction and navigate to:

[image]

Install the correct bit version